# Getting value from a input and put it in another input outside *ngFor

Tags: angular, input, ngfor

good morning.
How can I get the value from a input that is in `ngFor`?
For example, I have the following code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <!--th>title here<th-->
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ item.info[i].dataItem }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="{{ item.value }}">
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the previous code, I need to get the value of the input **total** that is inside the template that contains the `ngFor`, but the input that will contain this value will be outside the `ngFor`.

The complete code will be the next:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <!--th>title here<th-->
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ item.info[i].dataItem }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="{{ item.value }}">
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="totalT" id="totalT" value="The_value_of_this_input_must_be_the_same_that_input_with_total_id">
</div>
```

I don`t know how to get the value and put it in a input within the`ngFor`.

Best regards.

Comment: You are trying to connect n to 1. In the ngFor you have more input fields, from which of those you want the input in the bottom to have the value?

Comment: Well something looks amiss before you even get to answering the question.   id of total - in a loop. id should be unique across the whole web page...

Comment: I need that when the user of a click on the tr the value that contains this is passed to the input of below. Is every time the user selects a tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect two input fields to have the same value with `ngModel`. If you do something like this:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="someVar" type="text" id="text1">

<input [(ngModel)]="someVar" type="text" id="text2">
```

whatever you write in the first `input` the second `input` will get that value.

In your case try this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th><!--th>title here<th--></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>             
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index" >                    
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.info[i].dataItem}}</td>
      </tr>
      <input [(ngModel)]="someVar" type="text" name="total" id="total" value="{{ item.value }}"> 
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="someVar" type="text" name="totalT" id="totalT">
</div>
```

Comment: Using this code, how can I get the value from the second input and compare it with a ngIf?

Comment: You have the value from the second input in `someVar`. Define it in the Component like this `@Input() someVar;`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use @ViewChildren for this type of thing.

```
<input #inputs ....>
```

In the class behind component containing *ngFor

```
import {ViewChildren} from 'angular2/core'
export class myComponent {
 ...
@ViewChildren('inputs') inputs;
constructor(...) {}
}
```

Josh Morony gave an Ionic [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/video-viewchildren-vs-contentchildren-in-ionic/) that covered this part of Angular.
The idea is the same - Ionic builds on Angular...